# How to type an unknown data property from a SocketIO event

Tags: typescript, socket.io

I am using SocketIO to send events to a game client and I am having some issues as to how you would type a property which can consist of any arbitrary data type, whether it be an object, string, etc.

The event function that receives the data object is a generic `onPlayAnimation` function which maps into different components like so:

```
onPlayAnimation = (animation: {
  id: string;
  type: AnimationTypes;
  data: any;
}): void => {
  const Skill = getSkillAnimation(animation.type);

  if (Skill) {
    const skillInstance = new Skill(animation.data);

    game.addAnimation(animation.id, skillInstance);
  }
};
```

The argument provided to the mapped Skill constructor is currently set as `any` and in the mapped Skill constructor each Skill would expect its specific data:

```
constructor(props: FireballProps) {
  const { pos, radius, angle, speed } = props;
  ....
}
```

What I have considered so far is to break this function down to smaller event functions such as "onPlayFireballAnimation, onPlayMeteorAnimation" and have them be very specific but this seems like a lot of work for achieving more or less the same functionality I currently have by explicitly saying that the data could be anything, though with the drawback of not having it typed correctly.

Does anyone have an idea of how to achieve proper typing whilst not repeating code or is this inevitable?

Answer (score 0):

You can decorate the argument with the following type declaration:
let prova = null as string | AnimationMetadataType | object | FireballProps;

Then you would be able to access the common denominator for these specific types if they overlap.

If you want to check what type the property is, you can use the **is** keyword.

You can also use the user defined type guards although I am not sure how much do they fit to your use case.